# How are variable names useful in a declaration in an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, programming-languages, language-design

If we declare an interface, we have to specify the variable names as well.

For example in this sample

```
public interface ZipCodeServer {
    public String getCityName(int zipCode);
}
```

what is the purpose of `zipCode`. Ideally I would only like to have

```
public interface ZipCodeServer {
    public String getCityName(int);
}
```

without specifying its name. If I dont declare its name, I get a compile time error. Can anyone point me the exact purpose of declaring the variable names in an interface mandatorily

EDIT: I am not actually trying to convince anyone the variable names should not be there. I am asking what is the purpose of making it mandatory. Is it useful for any purpose to the compiler?

Comment: The purpose of parameter names is to give the code's author a chance to identify the purpose of the parameter.

Comment: You need to document the purpose of the parameter. Sometimes a simple name is enough documentation, and when not you still need a shorthand to identify the parameter (and "the [i-th] parameter" is pretty poor for that).

Comment: I agree, but shouldn't that be optional, rather than mandatory, if the method name is itself sufficient.

Comment: Making them optional increases syntactic and semantic complexity, requires additional implementation effort, and doesn't yield any benefit *for decent code*. Features start with -100 points you know.

Comment: Well, interfaces generally define contracts, right? If you have different implementations going off and defining the arguments to mean different things, interfaces would be far less useful than they currently are, and could possibly in fact be considered broken that way. Having names makes it absolutely clear what parameter should mean what. I really don't see any benefit to leaving off a name, and see benefits to requiring it.

Answer (score 3):

they aren't needed by compiler. they are needed by humans. interfaces are contracts, they often have comments (in your case: javadocs) that often refers to specific parameter. variable names helps you understand what function is doing.

because without variable names, you don't know what is doing the constructor

```
Point(double, double)
```

is it construct a point in cartesian or polar coordinate system? it's much more clear when you write:

```
Point(double x, double y)
```

or

```
Point(double distance, double radians)
```

Answer (score 0):

​It may be okay with just one argument. But how will methods like these can be understood?

```
public String getSome(int, int, int);
```